# How to have multiple timers in an event for different objects in Pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, pygame

So i'm creating a bullet-hell style game in Pygame inspired by Touhou, involving the player firing bullets in multiple different directions and at different fire rates. I've managed to borrow some code which allowed me to be able to implement the rapid fire shooting of a bullet, and then added onto that by creating multiple different bullet objects for a spread-shot. However, although i would like to be able to adjust the reload speed for each individual stream of bullet objects, i'm honestly stumped at how. Can anyone help me out here?

Here is the code involved for the bullets to shoot as intended, all with the same reload speed:

```
reloadSpeed = 50
shootingEvent = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
reloaded = True
```

(later on in the while loop):

```
if key[pygame.K_z]:
        if reloaded:
            bulletSound.stop()
            player.shoot()
            bulletSound.play()
            reloaded = False
            pygame.time.set_timer(shootingEvent, reloadSpeed)
```

Here is the shoot function in my Player class, and the Bullet class for context:

```
def shoot(self):
        bullet1N = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top, -4, -10, lb)
        bulletCentreN = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top, 0, -10,db)
        bullet3N = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top, 4, -10, lb)
        bullet1N2 = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top, -2, -10, db)
        bullet2N2 = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top, -1, -10, db)
        bullet3N2 = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top, 1, -10, db)
        bullet4N2 = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top, 2, -10, db)
```

(etc, etc, a lot of different types of bullets. The first number represents the number stream in the respective 'power' threshold, as i want different bullet streams as the power increases throughout the game; 'N' or 'S' represents whether the stream is for during normal fire or while holding shift, and the second number represents the power level this stream is used for.)

```
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if power < 16:
            if keystate[pygame.K_LSHIFT]:
                Group(bulletCentreS)

            else:
                Group(bullet1N)
                Group(bulletCentreN)
                Group(bullet3N)

        if power >= 16 and power < 48:
            if keystate[pygame.K_LSHIFT]:
                Group(bullet1S2)
                Group(bullet2S2)


            else:
                Group(bullet1N2)
                Group(bullet2N2)
                Group(bullet3N2)
                Group(bullet4N2)
```

(Group is just a function to add the bullets to a few sprite groups slightly more efficiently)

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, speedx, speedy, col):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((6, 6))
        self.image.set_alpha(100)
        self.image.fill(col)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.speedy = speedy
        self.speedx = speedx

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        # kill if it moves off the top of the screen
        if self.rect.bottom < 25:
            self.kill()
        if self.rect.x > WIDTH/2:
            self.kill()
```

As shown this results in every bullet of any pattern all firing at the same rate, albeit at different movement speeds in some occasions.

Edit: So thanks to Kingsley I have come to realise that I would somehow need to implement the shooting function into my Bullet class such that the fire rate of different streams can be adjusted through each Bullet object having a firerate attribute... but how would I implement this?

Comment: In order to help with adjusting the reload speed, we would need to see your code that's does this and be able to tell when it does this  — which you haven't included in your question.

Comment: @martineau ? I'm asking what code I would need to be able to have individual reload speeds, and I have provided the code I currently have that can only use a universal reload speed of 50, shown in the first code block. I have also provided when it executes, where i have used pygame.K_z.

Comment: Ryan, all the code in your question shows is that there's some global variable named `reloaded` that (presumably during the main event-processing loop) has _somehow_ been set to a truthy value, a call to `player.shoot()` will occur and then it will be reset to `False'. Not clear how that implements a "universal reload speed".

Answer (score 2):

A simple technique is to record the real-time of the "firing" event, and not allow further actions of that type until a time-delay is expired.

An easy way to get a usable timestamp is the PyGame [function](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) `pygame.time.getticks()`, which returns the ever-increasing number of milliseconds since startup.

Whenever the user actuates the firing mechanism, store the time.

```
fire_time_type1 = pygame.time.getticks()  # time of last shot
```

Also decide what the firing rate delay should be, for example:

```
RELOAD_DELAY_TYPE1 = 300   # milliseconds
```

Modify the user interface such that the firing procedure only completes after the delay has elapsed:

```
now = pygame.time.getticks()
if ( now > fire_time_type1 + RELOAD_DELAY_TYPE1 ):
    fire_weapon_type1()
    fire_time_type1 = now
else:
    # still waiting for re-load time delay
    # play weapon-too-hot sound, etc.
    pass
```

Obviously this mechanism can be worked into classes so the delay happens within the object, rather than externally like this example.

This method is easily implemented for different delays by simply storing more use-time records.

EDIT:

Perhaps a triggering class could maintain the state for the different types of 
 bullets.

```
### Gun object encapsulates enough detail to track the number of shots
### from a given magazine size, enforcing a reload-delay once the
### magazine is empty
class Gun:
    def __init__( self, name, magazine_size, reload_delay=300 ):
        self.name     = name
        self.shots    = 0
        self.mag_size = magazine_size
        self.reload   = reload_delay    # milliseconds
        self.use_time = 0

    def hasBullet( self ):
       """ Check that either a bullet is available, or that the
           reload delay has expired """
       now = pygame.time.getticks()
       if ( self.shots >= self.mag_size and now > self.use_time + self.reload ):
           self.shots = 0    # reload
           print( "Debug: [%s] reloaded after %d millisecs" % (self.name, self.reload ) )
       return ( self.shots < self.mag_size )

    def trackFiring( self ):
        """ keep track of the magazine limit, and when the shot was fired """
        self.shots    += 1
        self.use_time  = pygame.time.getticks()  # time of last shot             
        print( "Debug: [%s] fired, %d rounds left" % (self.name, self.mag_size - self.shots ) )



### ...

nail_gun = Gun( 'nail', 200, 500 )  
rockets  = Gun( 'rocket', 3, 1000 )
bfg      = Gun( 'BFG (oh yes!)', 1, 5000 )

### ...

# Player activates rocket launcher~
if ( rockets.hasBullet() ):
    rockets.trackFiring()
    shoot( ... )
```

Obviously the bullet shooting could be worked into the `Gun` class, but this is left as an exercise for the reader.

NOTE: I have not test-compiled this code, minor errors and omissions expected.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm honestly unsure whether the code you provided helps, and seems more like a different method of what I already gave. However, you provided an enlightening point in that it could be worked into classes happening within the object, and i believe that's exactly what I need. However, how would I do this? I know that I would use the reload time as one of its attributes, but how would i implement the 2 first blocks of code i provided into the Bullet class?

Comment: @Ryan_C - I don't think it really goes in the bullet class, it's at a level higher than that, before the bullet object is created.  If the mechanism needs to be "reloaded", no bullet should be produced.  I'll make an edit.

Comment: I read the edit, and honestly i think you misinterpreted. when the player shoots, the first 3 bullet objects will be created, and start moving depending on its x and y attributes, and as soon as 50ms have passed a duplicate of the 3 spawn, creating 3 streams of bullets. I would like to be able to make it such that i can change this refiring speed for individual bullet objects (e.g 100ms for the left and right streams and 50 for the centre). It is essentially how quickly say a machine gun fires rather than how long it takes to reload and begin firing it again, that's what i would like to adjust